# Weird Youtube Rendering on Google Chrome

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome, youtube, cinnamon

I am getting this weird rendering on YouTube videos in google chrome when running at 1080p (Image [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cEJN.jpg)). The problem goes away if I switch to 720p and returns when I switch back to 1080p. This only happens in the player, the rest of the web page renders fine. I am running Ubuntu 22.04 in cinnamon desktop environment on an HP Pavilion 14.

Graphics:
Device-1: Intel Alder Lake-P Integrated Graphics driver: i915 v: kernel
Device-2: Chicony HP True Vision 5MP Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 2880x1800~90Hz
OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Graphics (ADL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5

Comment: "HP Pavilion 14" is meaningless. That sub-brand/model spans more than a decade with hundreds of different configurations, Intel, Intel+Nvidia, Intel+AMD, AMD+Nvidia (???). We need the actual hardware specifications, namely the graphics.

Comment: To chime in: execute `inxi -G` in a terminal and copy the ouput into your question (**not** in to a comment). Further question: are you using Wayland or Xserver?